# ASP.NET Core UserManager FindByNameAsync Database Call or From Memory

Tags: github, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core RC2 and I'm trying determine if the `FindByNameAsync()` method in the `UserManager` class makes a database call to get the `IdentityUser` object or if it gets the `IdentityUser` object from memory.  I don't want to make an unnecessary database call because I can accomplish what I'm trying to do manually.  But the code would be cleaner if I can use `FindByNameAsync()`.

I tried finding the source code for the `UserManager` class on GitHub but I was unsuccessful.  Does anyone have any tips on how to search GitHub for the source code of a particular ASP.NET Core class?

Comment: Your database is SQL Server? SQL Server Management Studio has a profiler that allows you to see all queries against the database.

Comment: There's probably not a simple way to easily search for this type of thing. However, you probably know that UserManager is part of the ASP.NET Identity project. Microsoft's organization in GitHub is called `aspnet`. You can [go look at that organization](https://github.com/aspnet). Then find the Identity project. Then search within it for the class you seek.

Comment: @mason - Both comments were very helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @ClintB: You can use the "Find File" Option within a GitHub repository, as the typical convention is 1 class per file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UserManager, [code here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs) FindByNameAsync calls [UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs) FindByNameAsync and using the default EntityFramework implementation of UserStore it does query the database

Comment: Per mason's suggestion I used the SSMS Profiler and verified it does in fact make a database call.  Thanks!

Comment: Also please remember, the methods on UserManager are virtual, so there is nothing that prevents you from overriding them in `ApplicationUserManager` and add caching support (or do it on the underlying `IUserStore`, maybe even using the decorator pattern)